# VBA: Array of Range References

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

In VBA, I am trying to create an array of Range References.  Here's my current attempt:

```
Dim columnName()  As String
Dim colIndex()    As Long
Dim colRange()    As Range

colCount = 10
ReDim columnName(colCount)
ReDim colIndex(colCount)
ReDim colRange(1 To colCount)

columnName(ID) = "ID"
'etc

For i = 1 To UBound(columnName)
    colIndex(i) = WS.Range("A1", "ZZ1").Find(columnName(i), LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False).column
    colRange(i) = WS.Range(Cells(2, colIndex(i)), Cells(LastRowIndex, colIndex(i)))
    If 1 = 1 Then 'debugging
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Debug.Print colRange(i).Value
        Debug.Print colRange(i).Address
        colRange(i).Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    End If
```

When I try to store multiple references in an array, I get something like this:

```
i = 1
colIndex(i) = 8
Cells(2, colIndex(i)) = 123
Cells(LastRowIndex, colIndex(i)) =789
colRange(i) = Nothing
```

I have tried making colRange a variant, but nothing seems to work.  No solutions I found via google or StackOverflow seemed to address this.

Comment: Change `Dim colRange()    As Range` to `Dim colRange()    As String`

Comment: When I did that, it just gives `Compile error: Invalid qualifier` for the `Debug.Print` statements and the `colRange(i).Select` statement.

Comment: See the answer that I posted.

Comment: I added few other things so you may have to refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment above, here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim columnName() As String
    Dim rng As Range

    colCount = 10
    ReDim columnName(colCount)

    ID = 1

    columnName(ID) = "A"

    'MsgBox Cells(1, columnName(1)).Address
    Cells(1, columnName(1)).Value = "Blah Blah"

    Set rng = Cells(1, columnName(1))

    With rng
        MsgBox .Address
        .Value = "Something"
        '~~> Do whatever you want to do with that range here
    End With
End Sub
```

Avoid the use of `.Select`. Directly perform the action on the range like I have done above. [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)

Comment: I feel stupid.  I played with your code, change `rng` to `rng()`, change `Set rng...` to `Set rng(1) = Range(...)`, and kept comparing it to mine.  Eventually saw the tiny difference: I was using `colRange(i) = Range(...)` when I needed to be using `SET colRange(i) = Range(...)`.  Thank you for taking the time to write up this example, it was certainly helpful.  Thanks for the link as well!