# Excel VBA Iterate Array of Range Objects

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to iterate through an array of range references.

```
Dim labels As Collection
Set labels = New Collection
Dim myLabel As Range
Set myLabel = FindDataRow(mySearchterms, CurrentWorksheet) ' <- Returns a Range
labels.Add (myLabel)
```

Later I'm trying to iterate through those Range references and the following code does not work: I get a runtime error 424. I understand that an Object is required, but how did the label become a String.

```
Dim label As Variant
Set label = Nothing
For Each label In labels
    Debug.Print (label & " in: " & label.Row)
Next label
```

I have tried following [this other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372006/vba-array-of-range-references) but since I'm new to VBA in Excel I do not understand how the Range reference is put in the data structure and later retrieved/referenced to access the `label.Row` as I want above (at the point where it says "~~> Do whatever you want to do with that range here")

My understanding so far is that `labels`is a Collection and does not care about the type the items in it have. So I added `Range` references. But I can't retrieve them later. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets from the add method as that forces the value of the range to be added to the collection rather than the object:

```
labels.Add myLabel
```

Comment: Thank you! This took me the better part of a day.